# Using document.getElementById for textbox inputs

Tags: javascript, html, web, innerhtml

I wanted the equation to take user input and give a response based on the output. The equation works just fine, I can't get it to print anything. For example the answer is 10 and it prints 10 along with a comment. Maybe its something I'm looking over, or my code could be horribly wrong. Help?

```
<html>
<body>

    Total=3.21+9.63 x S //equation
    <form id="function" onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = 3.21 + (9.63    *parseInt(c.value))">
        =3.21+(9.63 *
        <input name="c" type="number" step="any">) =
        <output name="o"> </output>

        <input type="button" value="Predict" name="myButton" onClick="myMath()"> </form>

    <div id="mys1"></div>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        //my concept
        function myMath() {
            if (((document.function.o.output) < -30))
                document.getElementById("mys1").innerHTML = 'That'
            s a little cold!'; 

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open the browser's error console. It tells you what the syntax error is and on which line.

Comment: Hint: look at the quotes you've used on the string you set to the innerHTML - the string 'ends' before you think it does!

Comment: `<output>` elements don't have `.value` attributes. And you seem to be accessing it in an invalid way.

Answer (score 0):

This bit is invalid javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mys1").innerHTML = 'That's a little cold!'
```

It should look like this:

```
document.getElementById("mys1").innerHTML = "That's a little cold!"
```

To avoid the missing `'` which should be causing an error in the web console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>

Total=3.21+9.63 x S //equation
<form id="function" onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = 3.21 + (9.63    *parseInt(c.value))">
    =3.21+(9.63 *
    <input name="c" type="number" step="any">) =
    <output id="o"> </output>

    <input type="button" value="Predict" name="myButton" onClick="myMath()" </form>

<div id="mys1"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    //my concept
    function myMath() {
        var x = document.getElementById("o").value;
        if (x < -30){
            document.getElementById("mys1").innerHTML = "That's a little cold!"; 
        }
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I took the value out of the output element and compared it to -30.
You should use curly brackets after 'if' statements.
Also your string : 'That's a little cold!' is already ended after 'That'.